# Использование переменной как строки

Tags: php

Добрый день!

Возникла необходимость парсить XML файл с не уникальными ключами, и передать результат с сервера на клиент. Структура XML заранее известна, и к изменению не планируется. Поэтому хотелось бы сделать функцию, которая на вход получает путь до элементов, и дальше уже складывает их:

```
    $xml_name='test/example.xml';
    $ParamsUsr = simplexml_load_file($xml_name);
    $XMLpath= 'CarTypeList->CarType';
    foreach ($XML_child->$XMLpath->children() as $character) {
        echo $character->getname().' значение:'. $character;
    }
```

К сожалению, данный код работать не будет, т.к. переменная $XMLpath воспринимается, не как путь, а как объект XML. Как сделать так, чтобы при исполнении кода переменная воспринимался как текст? 
Т.е. вот так:

```
 foreach ($XML_child->CarTypeList->CarType->children() as $character)
```

Спасибо!

Comment: кто такой `XML_child` и откуда он взялся? почему нельзя воспользоваться `xpath` ? Может xml приведете и скажете что оттуда именно хотите брать?

Comment: Добрый день! Недогуглил. Действительно метод xpath решил всю проблему. Спасибо!